# Google Analytics SDK for Android Code Implementation

Tags: android

Good day
I have manage to create my small and simple application, work with screens and layouts but I cannot make work the Google analytics.

I think my problems are regarding the code placement, please take a look and tell me where I am wrong.

First I have add and build the path for libGoogleAnalytics.jar

at manifest,

```
</activity>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" ></uses-permission>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

at package,

```
package com.av0001;

import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Av0001 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        tracker.startNewSession("UA-25516864-1", this);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
public void myonclick1(View view) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,Check2.class);
    startActivity(mIntent);
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Thank you for using, enjoy browsing :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();  
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.stopSession();
}
}
```

So I am stack here, it's running for three days almost,I have no reports at all.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup a session but did you call trackEvent? I am thinking you are missing that.
Another thing to test is setup fiddler tracing and see if anything goes to the Analytics endpoint.

HTH

Comment: I think that is what you are talking about  ,
Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
tracker.trackEvent(
"Clicks",  // Category
"Button",  // Action
"clicked", // Label
77);       // Value
}
});
What should I write at this "NewEventButton" because if I select "Button01" the application stops working. Should I do something else? Thanks

Comment: Will this work, if I want track the fireup of the application, @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
     tracker.startNewSession("UA-25516864-1", this);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen"); Should I put then something else or the "tracker.stopSession" onDestroy is enough. Thanks

Comment: So far I dont have something, must waiting for some time, I hope not days as I read at other posts!

Comment: Ok, works but I dont which setup has worked, I have a green status now, must continue checking at first.